# How do I bind a function to a Backbone Router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to bind my `router` to a method in my router.  Here is the `router`:

```
define(function(require) {

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var User = require('models/user.model');

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    user: null,

    initialize: function() {
      _.bind(this.updateUser, this);
      Backbone.on('userAuthenticated', this.updateUser);

      this.user = new User();
      this.user.fetch();
    },

    updateUser: function() {
      debugger;
    }
  });

  return Router;
});
```

I am binding the method `updateUser` to my `router`.  When the event `userAuthenticated` is triggered, then I want to run the code in `updateUser`.  The event gets thrown and the method gets called, but when I get into the `updateUser` method, my `this` is not the `router` like I expect, but the global object.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_.bind()` returns a function, so you might consider something like `this.updateUser = _.bind(this.updateUser, this)`.

Answer (score 1):

I pointed out in a couple comments that `_.bind()` returns a new function, which your example doesn't assign to anything.  However, a simpler solution would be to use the optional third argument to `on()`:

```
Backbone.on('userAuthenticated', this.updateUser, this);
```

[Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on)

Comment: Your comments on my answer were totally correct, this is the right answer.

Comment: How would this solution work if I needed to pass some parameters to the `updateUser` method?

Comment: You would have to put `var that = this;` at the top of `initialize` and replace `this.updateUser` in this answer with `function(event){ that.updateUser(params);}`

Comment: @jhamm: I'm not sure what you have in mind, but the Backbone.Events `trigger()` method accepts a list of args that are passed on to the event handler.  If your params are known at subscription time, there are several options, e.g. you could add them to `this`.

Comment: @psquared - Could you give me an example?